# Android application crashes on real device when keyboard is used

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am new to Android development so please forgive me if this question seems trivial.

I am trying to run my android app on my phone(HTC One) but it stops working the minute I use keyboard to fill a text area. I am aware of the fix for emulators provided by eclipse but could anyone please provide me a fix for using it on a real device?

Thank you!

Update:
Please find the error log by LogCat below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24443): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(24443): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.widget.EditText@421edb70"

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:114)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc.updateTipAndFinalBill(CrazyTipCalc.java:81)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc.access$1(CrazyTipCalc.java:79)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.example.crazytipcalc.CrazyTipCalc$1.onTextChanged(CrazyTipCalc.java:73)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7452)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:7511)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:9317)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:962)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:496)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:212)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:30)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:94)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:49)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:155)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:189)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:5432)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5250)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2726)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7142)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1369)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1369)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1369)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1369)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2013)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1490)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2414)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1940)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4048)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4004)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3530)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4648)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4627)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3347)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)

E/AndroidRuntime(24443):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.crazytipcalc;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CrazyTipCalc extends Activity {

    private static final String TOTAL_BILL = "TOTAL_BILL";
    private static final String CURRENT_TIP = "CURRENT_TIP";
    private static final String BILL_WITHOUT_TIP = "BILL_WITHOUT_TIP";

    private double billBeforeTip;
    private double tipAmount;
    private double finalBill;

    EditText billBeforeTipET;
    EditText tipAmountET;
    EditText finalBillET;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crazy_tip_calc);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            billBeforeTip = 0.0;
            tipAmount = .15;
            finalBill = 0.0;
        } else{
            billBeforeTip = savedInstanceState.getDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP);
            tipAmount = savedInstanceState.getDouble(CURRENT_TIP);
            finalBill = savedInstanceState.getDouble(TOTAL_BILL);
        }
        billBeforeTipET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billEditText);
        tipAmountET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tipEditText) ;
        finalBillET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finalBillEditText);

        billBeforeTipET.addTextChangedListener(billBeforeTipListener);

    }

    private TextWatcher billBeforeTipListener = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
                billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());

            } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                billBeforeTip = 0.0;
            }

            updateTipAndFinalBill();

        }

    };

    private void updateTipAndFinalBill(){

        double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.toString());

        double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip*tipAmount);

        finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, billBeforeTip);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crazy_tip_calc, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you share your code and the error logs

Comment: What was the error message in logcat?

Comment: Please find the error log above. Sorry for the unclear image. I am not able to save it to a text file for some reason. When I am trying to export the error log, it just shows me an empty text file.

Comment: At which line you got Error??

Comment: Please find the updated LogCat in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `updateTipAndFinalBill()` method, you are calling the following:

```
double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.toString());
```

Firstly, `tipAmountET` is an `EditText`, so this line should be:

```
double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
```

Secondly, you should surround this with a `try-catch` block, just like you did in the `onTextChanged()` method of your `TextWatcher`.

```
try
{
    double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.toString());`

You need to replace it with: `Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());`

```
private void updateTipAndFinalBill() {

    try {
        double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
        double finalBill = billBeforeTip + (billBeforeTip*tipAmount);

        finalBillET.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));

    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        /* Whatever you want to do when there is no tip amount. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Are there more places where I need to change it? Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: After changing it, can you share the exception you receive now?

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(27008): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: Yeah so you are parsing an empty string as a double, and it's not a double. I'll update my code for you in a minute.

Comment: That worked! I surrounded it with try- catch block and it worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.toString());
```

here you are just trying to convert EditText to String which is in double format. So it can't get any value and because of this you got error. So change it

```
 double tipAmount = Double.parseDouble(tipAmountET.getText().toString());
```